# How to configure an Hbase cluster in fully distributed mode using Docker

Tags: docker, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I'm setting up an HBase cluster in fully distributed mode, with 1 HMaster node and 3 Regionservers node

My `hbase-site.xml` file contain

```
<configuration>
   <property>
     <name>hbase.master</name>
     <value>hbase.master:60000</value>
   </property>
<property>
   <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
   <value>hdfs://hadoop.master:9000/data/hbase</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
   <value>true</value>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
   <value>2181</value>
 </property>
 <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/tmp</value>
 </property>
 <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>hbase.master</value>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

My hadoop cluster is running normally.

I run Zookeeper on the same machine with hbase master, and the configuration file `zoo.cfg` as it default value.

When I start cluster and view the Hbase Master web UI, all the Regionserver appear in the list, but when I try to create table or something else command such as `hbase>status` they always show Exeception:

```
ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.PleaseHoldException: Master is initializing
 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.checkInitialized(HMaster.java:1889)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterRpcServices.getClusterStatus(MasterRpcServices.java:695)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.MasterProtos$MasterService$2.callBlockingMethod(MasterProtos.java:42406)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2033)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:107)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor.consumerLoop(RpcExecutor.java:130)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$1.run(RpcExecutor.java:107)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

So what's wrong with my cluster?

Comment: No ,I think this problem is not related to docker version, I am also getting this error intermittently. In my case hregionservers not able to connect to zookeeper, because of some host conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that I'm using Docker version 1.8.2
After fully remove Docker then install the older one (1.7.0) then my script run normally